# Css ul display is none when hover display is block

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, web, dropdownbox

I'm working on a dropdown box but the only thing that doenst want to work is when I hover over the word Info in the unordered list the dropdownbox is not displayed.

I know I have `display:none;` in `ul style` but can you change that to `display:block;` when hovered over the word info?

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="Menu">
     <li><a href="Index.html">Home </a></li>
     <li><a href="Info.html">Info </a>
          <ul style="display:none;">
             <li><a href="Index.html">Program</a></li>
             <li><a href="Index.html">Getting Started</a><li>
             <li><a href="Index.html">Credits</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="Community.html">Video </a></li>
     <li><a href="Store.html">server </a></li>
     <li><a href="Profile.html">Profile </a></li>
     <li><a href="Help">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS Code:

```
#Menu {
list-style:none;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:Bold;
padding:14px 0 0;
width:415px;
margin-top:0;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}

#menu { list-style:none;}
li:hover > ul {display:list-item;}
li ul { margin:0; padding:0; position:absolute;z-index:5;padding-top:6px;}
li { float:left; margin-left:10px; }
li ul li { float:none; margin:0; display:inline;}
li ul li a {display:block; padding:6px 10px; background:#333; white-space:nowrap;}
li { display: list-item; text-align: -webkit-match-parent;}
ul { border:0; font-size:100%; font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}
```

Help in advanced. any help is apreciated :)
also post a code not only telling me whats wrong thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `#Menu` before your css class names : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X8py6/)**

like: `#Menu li:hover > ul {display:list-item;}`

> **NOTIC:** css Class names are  Case-Sensitive

Comment: Thank you. your anwer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this is because the html code contains an inline `display:none`.
In the inner `<ul>`, we should remove `<ul style="display:none;">` in the above html.